# Fetch content on onpaste event in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to fetch the data on onpaste event. `checkPasteLength` gets invoked when I try to paste some text but `event.key` returns `undefined` and `event.clipboardData.getData('textarea')` returns `null`

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control" onpaste={checkPasteLength}>
       <lightning-textarea name="info" value={info} onchange={handleChange} variant="label-hidden"></lightning-textarea>
</div>

checkPasteLength(event){
    console.log(event.key);
    console.log(event.clipboardData.getData('textarea'));
}
```

Is there a way to get the value on `onpaste`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works fine

```
 checkPasteLength(e){
        var clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;

    console.log(clipboardData.getData('Text'));
}
```

here is the PG https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/9NLbuG8pA/1/edit

Comment: yeah,this works